# Chai-As-Promised is eating assertion errors

Tags: selenium, testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using **chai-as-promised** + **mocha** for writing some **selenium-webdriver** tests. Since webdriver extensively uses **promises**, I imagined it would be better if I used chai-as-promised for those type of tests.

The problem is that when the tests fail, the error is not being caught properly by mocha, and it just fails without outputting anything.

Sample code:

```coffee
it 'tests log', (next) ->
  log = @client.findElement(By.css("..."))
  Q.all([
    expect(log.getText()).to.eventually.equal("My Text")
    expect(log.findElement(By.css(".image")).getAttribute('src'))
      .to.eventually.equal("/test.png")
  ]).should.notify(next)
```

According to [documented behaviour](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/#working-with-non-promisefriendly-test-runners), **chai-as-promised** should pass the errors along to mocha when the expectation fails. Right?

As a variation,

I've also tried these, but to no avail:

#### #2

```coffee
# same, no error on failure

it 'tests log', (next) ->
  log = @client.findElement(By.css("..."))
  Q.all([
    expect(log.getText()).to.eventually.equal("My Text")
    expect(log.findElement(By.css(".image")).getAttribute('src'))
      .to.eventually.equal("/test.png")
  ]).should.notify(next)
```

#### #3

```coffee
# same, no error shown on failure

it 'tests log', (next) ->
  log = @client.findElement(By.css("..."))
  expect(log.getText()).to.eventually.equal("My Text")
  .then ->
     expect(log.findElement(By.css(".image")).getAttribute('src'))
       .to.eventually.equal("/test.png").should.notify(next)
```

#### #4

```coffee
## DOES NOT EVEN PASS

it 'tests log', (next) ->            
  log = @client.findElement(By.css("..."))
  Q.all([
    expect(log.getText()).to.eventually.equal("My Text")
    expect(log.findElement(By.css(".image")).getAttribute('src'))
      .to.eventually.equal("/test.png")
  ])
  .then ->
    next()
  .fail (err) ->
    console.log(err)
  .done()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're having two different issues:

First, you need to return a promise at the end of your tests (e.g. `Q.all([...]);` in your first test should be `return Q.all([...])`.

Second, I found that `chai-as-promised` doesn't seem to work unless used with `mocha-as-promised`.

Here's an example of `mocha-as-promised` with two assertions that will cause the test to fail.

```js
/* jshint node:true */

/* global describe:false */
/* global it:false */

'use strict';

var Q = require('q');

require('mocha-as-promised')();

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('the test suite', function() {
  it('uses promises properly', function() {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        defer.resolve(2);
      }, 1000);

    return Q.all([
      expect(0).equals(0),

      // the next line will fail
      expect(1).equals(0),

      expect(defer.promise).to.eventually.equal(2),

      // the next line will fail
      expect(defer.promise).to.eventually.equal(0)
    ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: About the first point, I'm using coffee-script, so the `return` is mostly implicit for the last line of any function.

Comment: Just want to note that mocha-as-promised seems to be unnecessary these days. According to https://github.com/domenic/mocha-as-promised Mocha 1.18.0 has built-in promise support. The documentation at https://mochajs.org/ seems to agree.