# Chai expected [Function] to throw an (error) not passing the test (Using Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

**The question:**

I'm using Chai to do the tests and I seem to be stuck on testing an expected error:

*Chai expected [Function] to throw an (error)*

**Current code:**

Here's the code of the test:

```
describe('Do something', function () {

    it('should remove a record from the table', function (done) {

        storage.delete(ID, done);

    });

    it('should throw an error when the lookup fails', function () {

         expect(storage.delete.bind(storage, ID)).to.throw('Record not found');
    });
});
```

Here's the code of the function:

```
delete: function (id, callback) {
    //  Generate a Visitor object
    visitor = new Visitor(id);

    /*  Delete the visitor that matches the queue an
        cookie provided. */
    tableService.deleteEntity(function (error, response) {

        //  If successful, go on.
        if (!error) {
            // Do something on success.
        }
        //  If unsuccessful, log error.
        else {
            if (error.code === 'ResourceNotFound') {
                throw new Error('Record not found');
            }

            //  For unexpected errros.
            else {

                throw new Error('Table service error (delete): ' + error);

            }
        }
        if (callback) callback();
    });

},
```

**Attempted solutions:**

I've tried multiple variations of calling expect function (including calling anonymous function:

```
expect(function() {storage.delete(ID);}).to.throw('Record not found');
```

Bind, as provided in the example,

and the basic one of

```
expect(storage.delete(ID)).to.throw('Record not found');
```

I've also tried substituting the throw parameter from 'Record not found' to multiple things including directing the input to an already created error (Error), and creating a new error in the parameter (new Error('Record not found'));

**Possible causes:**

I have a suspicion that the error is not being thrown because it takes a while for the test to communicate with the database to delete the record, however I am not sure of how I could remedy that.

Additionally, it seems that the test that runs right after this one actually returns the error that was supposed to be returned on THIS test.

Comment: Is `tableService.deleteEntity` synchronous?

Comment: Then `tableService.deleteEntity` never throws an exception. It's a nested handler that does which runs asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks! In that case perhaps you could recommend a method for testing this error throw? Or a way of rewriting the function that would make it possible to test?

Comment: Return promises instead.

Comment: What's a promise in this context?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and any implementation, like `Q` or `Bluebird`

Comment: Examine [chai-as-promises](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931737/chai-as-promised-is-eating-assertion-errors)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies guys! Wrestling with Promises now, never used them before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given (from comments) that `tableService.deleteEntity` is asynchronous, it is impossible to test that `throw`. And the code itself is invalid. Because the thrown exception won't be caught, it will be unhandled as it was thrown in a different tick. Read more about [Asynchronous error handling in JavaScript](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/12/31/asynchronous-error-handling-in-javascript/) and [unhandled exceptions in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

In other words such a function cannot be tested for throwing errors:

```
function behaveBad(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        throw new Error('Bad. Don\'t do this');
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: I see. I'll give Promises and Chai as Promises a shot now, thanks for the answer!